# using webpack to create a object based on all JSON files in a project

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a need to generate a JSON object for a Vue.js app based off of all of the .json files in a certain directory. Essentially, I need to iterate through each .json file, append a few of its properties to the JSON object, and use that JSON object in the app.

Can this be done via a webpack loader? Or should I be looking at doing this another way?

I created a `vue.config.js` to add my custom loader:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rule('json')
      .test(/\.json$/)
      .include
        .add(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/json'))
        .end()
      .use('json-army-list-loader')
        .loader(path.resolve('webpack/loaders/my-loader.js'))
        .end();
  }
};
```

And I have a basic `my-loader.js`

```
var myObj = {};

module.exports = function (source) {
  try {
    myObj[source.category].push(source.name);
  } catch (e) {
    myObj[source.category] = [source.name];
  }

  return JSON.stringify(myObj);
};
```

But I'm stuck here and not sure:

1. how to test all of this (which is leading to all these other questions)
2. if my loader is even being used
3. if my loader is generating the object it's return correctly
4. how to access this object in my Vue app

Comment: I think a Wepback loader would be unnecessarily complex for this task. It's much simpler to import those `.json` files directly in your app code, where it's being used.

Comment: It's 100s of JSON files though. Processing them all with a webpack loader would allow me to keep the app's size low and fetch them as they're needed wholly (and not just for a property or two).

Comment: You still don't need Webpack loaders for that. You could write a utility script that generates a JSON file based on the original JSON files, and then have your app import that generated file.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually do this within your app leveraging `require.context` which webpack provides to you:

```
let myObj = {}
const files = require.context('./json', true, /\.json$/i);

files.keys().map((key) => {
  const json = files(key)
  Object.keys(json).forEach((k) => {
    myObj[k] = json[k]
  })
})

window.myObj = myObj
```

Here we're leveraging webpacks `require.context()`, which has the following arguments:

```
require.context(directory, useSubdirectories = false, regExp = /^\.\//)
```

We can use this to create . a glob expression for only files in our `json` directory ending with `.json`.

The `files.keys()` method gives us the name of the file and calling the output of our `require.context()` as a function and passing in the key gives us back the content.

Finally we can apply `Object.keys(...)` to loop over each of our `key: value` pairs in our `json file` and apply it to a global `myObj` which we can then hang off the window (yikes..)